# Вывод строки Java

Tags: java

Как сделать так чтобы в консоль выводилась строка состоящая только из чётных или нечётных символов строки введённой пользователем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получите из строки массив и выводите каждый второй символ.
Получить из строки массив можно при помощи метода `toCharArray()`. Для вывода каждого второго символа используйте счётчик. Если значение счётчика чётное - выводите число. Если нет - не выводите. `count % 2 > 0` - это выражение вернёт true, если значения счётчика чётное.